# UIStoryboardSegue causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash the second time around

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I've been trying to create a UIStoryboardSegue that mimics the "Cover Vertical" modal segue, but makes the view "Uncover," so that the segues look natural together. Here's my UIStoryboardSegue child class:

```
//RetreatVertical.m

#import "RetreatVertical.h"
@implementation RetreatVertical

-(void)perform {
    UIView *oldView = [self.sourceViewController view];
    UIView *newView = [self.destinationViewController view];
    [oldView.window insertSubview:newView belowSubview:oldView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        oldView.center = CGPointMake(oldView.center.x, oldView.center.y + oldView.frame.size.height); }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){ [oldView removeFromSuperview]; }
     ];
}

@end
```

When the user taps a button, a UIViewController slides into focus using the modal segue "Cover Vertical." When the user taps a button on the new UIViewController, that UIViewController slides back down, revealing the old UIViewController (using my custom segue "RetreatVertical"). That all works fine, however, whenever I tap any other button or interface element after both animations are completed, the app crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS." I have no idea why, and the past hour of searching hasn't come up with anything.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Why doesn't this strategy work?

```
- (void) perform {
    UIView *sourceView = [self.sourceViewController view];
    UIView *destView = [self.destinationViewController view];
    [[self.sourceViewController superview] insertSubview:destView belowSubview:sourceView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        sourceView.center = CGPointMake(sourceView.center.x, sourceView.center.y + sourceView.frame.size.height); }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){ [sourceView removeFromSuperview]; }
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing around with the Application Window directly (and it's subviews) is always tricky and extremely hard to get right; there's a lot of hidden stuff going on that you can't possibly account for. So lets just change your hierarchy slightly to make everything easier.

**Right now you have:**

***A** = Root VC*

***B** = New VC*

Transition:  **Window** { **A** -----> **B** }

**Better solution:**

***A** = Root VC*

***B** = New VC*

***C** = Old VC*

Transition: Window { **A** { **C** -----> **B** } }

Meaning that have your Root just be a plain VC with a blank view that you push your views on top of. This will allow you to easily do whatever animations you wish without having to worry about screwing up your main window.

Comment: Yes and no. My point here is that if at all possible, never screw with the main Window. Instead, push and pop your VC's off of the root VC without touching the Window itself. But you should absolutely create a new VC each time, and make sure to release your old one. Here's a link to a nice [Tutorial](http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/2012/02/01/storyboard-custom-segue-for-custom-pushviewcontroller-animation/)

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement the strategy you're proposing. I understand the relationships I need to have for a successful solution, but I can't figure out how to put it all together. I modified my original post to include my failed attempt at using your idea. Thank you so much for commenting, I'd love if you could still help out!

Comment: Oh, okay... I need to pop VCs on the Root VC, I was doing that all wrong again and again. How do I pop things on top of the root? (sorry about deleting that previous comment, by the way!)

Comment: **Check out my new edit--** why doesn't that work? Sorry to be so demanding, but I'm really trying to puzzle through this and just can't figure it out. :/

Comment: I think your ultimate problem here is that you're confusing View Controllers with Views. A UIStoryboardSegue is used to transition from one VC to another VC, however all of your code is focused on moving Views around and the VC's are never appropriately handled. You need to have a management system for your VC's, e.g a NavigationController, that you push and pop your VC's off of AFTER you do your custom view animations. I linked in a good tutorial above that showcases the needed end result.